# Scoring of trivia game becomes inaccurate after 2nd game

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I have a trivia game that is 10 timed questions.  A wrong answer is supposed to output 0 points.  A correct answer is supposed to output the remaining of the 20,000 milliseconds converted to a 100 point scale.

Right now the game works on the first game.  Then, if the user keeps playing for a second time, the points for each question becomes incorrect.  For example, incorrect answers begin to have a variety of points from 1 to 100 and also correct answers sometimes have 0 points and also sometimes wrong point totals.  So I am guessing some variable is possibly not resetting on the second game so it is causing the points to be a little off.

I posted all the code that deals with the algorithm.  My question is how I can get this code to output the correct answer no matter how many times the user plays before closing the app.

QuestionView.java

```
public class QuestionView extends Activity  {

    int correctAnswers = 0;
    int wrongAnswers = 0;
    int answer = 0;
    int i = 0;

    long score = 0;

    long startTime = 20000;
    long interval = 1000;
    long points;

    boolean timerHasStarted = false;

    String category;

    Button answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4;
    TextView question, pointCounter, questionNumber, timeCounter, timeremaining;
    AdView adView;

    ArrayList<Question> queries;
    public static ArrayList<Long> pointsPerQuestion = new ArrayList<Long>(10);
    Timer cdTimer;

    ProgressBar bar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.questionview);

        answer1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        answer2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        answer3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        answer4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer4);

        question = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);

        category = getIntent().getStringExtra("category");
        queries = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("queries");

        questionNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.questionnumber);
        timeremaining = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeremaining);

        cdTimer = new Timer(startTime, interval);

        bar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        bar.setIndeterminate(false);
        bar.setMax(20000);

        tracker.sendView("/QuestionView - Started Quiz");

        loadQuestion();
    }

    public void loadQuestion() {

        if(i == 10) {

            cdTimer.cancel();
            endQuiz();

        } else {

            if(!timerHasStarted) {
                cdTimer.start();
                timerHasStarted = true;
            } else {
                cdTimer.start();
                timerHasStarted = false;
            }

            answer = queries.get(i).getCorrectAnswer();

            question.setText(queries.get(i).getQuery());

            answer1.setText(queries.get(i).getA1());
            answer2.setText(queries.get(i).getA2());
            answer3.setText(queries.get(i).getA3());
            answer4.setText(queries.get(i).getA4());

            answer1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    queries.get(i).setSelectedAnswer(0);
                    if(answer == 0) {
                        correctAnswers++;
                        correct();
                    } else {
                        wrongAnswers++;
                        incorrect();
                    }
                }
            });

            answer2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    queries.get(i).setSelectedAnswer(1);
                    if(answer == 1) {
                        correctAnswers++;
                        correct();
                    } else {
                        wrongAnswers++;
                        incorrect();
                    }
                }
            });

            answer3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    queries.get(i).setSelectedAnswer(2);
                    if(answer == 2) {
                        correctAnswers++;
                        correct();
                    } else {
                        wrongAnswers++;
                        incorrect();
                    }
                }
            });

            answer4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    queries.get(i).setSelectedAnswer(3);
                    if(answer == 3) {
                        correctAnswers++;
                        correct();
                    } else {
                        wrongAnswers++;
                        incorrect();
                    }
                }
            });
        } 
    }

    public ArrayList<Question> getQueries() {
        return queries;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Long> getPointsPerQuestion() {
        return pointsPerQuestion;
    }

    public void correct() {
        pointsPerQuestion.add(points); 
        score = score + points;
        i++;
        loadQuestion();
    }

    public void incorrect() {
        long zero = 0;
        pointsPerQuestion.add(zero);
        i++;
        loadQuestion();
    }

    public class Timer extends CountDownTimer {

        public Timer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            points = 0;
            if(i >= 9) {
                cdTimer.cancel();
                pointsPerQuestion.add(points);
                endQuiz();
            } else {
                wrongAnswers++;
                incorrect();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            bar.setProgress((int) millisUntilFinished);
            points = millisUntilFinished / 200;
            timeremaining.setText("Score remaining: " + points);
            if(i < 10) {
                questionNumber.setText("Question " + (i + 1) + " of 10");
            }
        }
    }

    public void endQuiz() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionView.this, Results.class);
        intent.putExtra("correctAnswers", correctAnswers);
        intent.putExtra("wrongAnswers", wrongAnswers);
        intent.putExtra("score", score);
        intent.putExtra("pointsPerQuestion", pointsPerQuestion);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("queries", queries);
        intent.putExtra("category", category);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Here is a `Question` object:

```
exodus.add(new Question("6th", "3rd", "5th", "4th", 2, "Name that plague:  All livestock dies", -1, "Exodus 9:6"));
```

In my `Results` class, which is where the points per question is displayed, this is the line that displays the points:

```
scoreTV.setText("You received " + QuestionView.getPointsPerQuestion().get(x) + " out of a possible 100 points.");
```

Everything else is pretty much in my `QuestionView` above.  Let me know if you still need something else.

First 3 Strings are answers A (index 0), B (index 1), C (index 2) and D (index 3).  The first int is the correct answer.  The 5th String is the question.  The second int is set to the answer selected by user during quiz.  Last String is the bible verse where the answer is found.

Comment: Where is the `QuestionView` being created? Where is the loop to start over? There's some other code we need to see (maybe the `main()`, though it's hard to tell how it's structured). I would guess that you're creating that object once and re-using it, in which case the instance variables keep state. You can either create a new one each time, or define a `resetScores()` method to reset everything and call that at the beginning of each loop.

Comment: Um, I think I understood your comment.  I edited in something at the bottom of my opening post.  Let me know if you need further code.

Comment: Should trivia be a tag?